# how to make the output from checkbox to select statment?

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-apex

I am currently using apex 19.1. I have this problem where I can't (or don't know how to) select certain columns from checkbox meaning I have this checkbox

[image: checkbox]

which gives me the ability to check the columns names I want to use that output (:P3_COLUMN)  from the check box to select a specific columns in a table. My solution was :

```
select :P3_COLUMN
 from INPUT_TABLE$
```

I also tried :

```
select case :P3_COLUMN when 'currency' then currency when 'nationality'       then nationality end as test from input_table
```

which gave me this output

[image: SQL Statment output picture]

and

```
DECLARE
str varchar2(100);
BEGIN
str := 'select ' || replace(:P3_COLUMN, ':', ',') || ' from input_table';
execute immediate str;
END;
```

which gave me this error

[image: SQL STATMENT ERROR PICTURE]

I don't know what to do, any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: You should probably have an option for when none of the boxes are checked, when `:P3_COLUMN` will be NULL. That looks like the problem with your second and third images. Apex session state is tricky, `:P3_COLUMN` might be getting assigned a value **after** your SQL query runs. The Debug tool can help troubleshoot those problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a walkthrough (my page is #51). Suppose that we want to display some column from Scott's `DEPT` table.

- create a region whose type is classic report
- create a page item (let's call it `P51_COLS` which is a select list item; its source is a query which looks like this:

  ```
  select column_name d,
         column_name r
  from user_Tab_columns
  where table_name = 'DEPT'
  ```

  Page action on selection should be "Submit page"
- region's source should be a PL/SQL function body that returns a SQL query and look like this:

  ```
  return 'select case when :P51_COLS = ''DEPTNO'' then to_char(deptno )
                      when :P51_COLS = ''DNAME''  then dname
                      when :P51_COLS = ''LOC''    then loc
                 end as result 
          from dept';
  ```

  Its "Page items to submit" should be set to `P51_COLS`

That's it ... run the page; select any column from the select list item and the result should be displayed.

Yes, I know - the query itself looks *stupid* as you have to name all cases. For some reason, Apex expects literally `return 'select ...'` statement. Concatenation, replace function, ... won't work. Perhaps someone knows why or - even better - can demonstrate how to workaround it. Meanwhile, try what's been written above.

Answer (score 0):

first option use server side condition on the columns.

second option use dynamic sql> create function returns sql statement> call the function in your region source.